# How to read an array in twig

Tags: php, symfony

I have an array of json composed this way :

```
[{"name":K,"age":14,"job":null}]
```

I want to know have to read it in twig. I've tried so many solution like those:

```
array|json_encode()
array|raw
{{ attribute(array, item) }}
```

But no one of those solutions are working

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can simply iterate the json without any preparements

```
[{"name":K,"age":14,"job":null},{"name":K,"age":17,"job":null}]


{% for key, value in array %}
   {{ value.age ~ "-" }}
{% endfor %}
```

prints  `14-17-`

Comment: this will work if a json array, instead i have an array of json.

Comment: you have a json array with objects, i tried with the code you supplied and it works

Comment: could you share the output of  `print_r($your_array)`  ?

Comment: `[{"name":xx","adress":"xx","psotal_code":"11},{"name":zz","adress":"zz","psotal_code":"22"}] `. Here's my real array.

Comment: if that is the real array it is not working for you because of the errors it contains, there are loads of unclosed doublequote escapes like `"name":xx"` must be `"name":"xx"`

Comment: you need to add the code to your question how you retrieve the array and pass it to the view, e.g the controller code